# Why array address space always end in 'c' when array[3]

Tags: c++

I have been playing with arrays and noticed that when the declared array size is 3 (int array[3], the address space always ends in 'c'. What does this 'c' at the end of the first address space stand for?

```
 int arr[3];
    cout<<"MA 1: "<<&arr[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"MA 2: "<<&arr[1]<<endl;
    cout<<"MA 3: "<<&arr[2]<<endl;
```

output

```
MA 1: 0x7ffe3269ca7c
MA 2: 0x7ffe3269ca80
MA 3: 0x7ffe3269ca84
```

If make the array size anything else, *i.e. array[!3], the start address space ends in 0. E.g...

```
int arr[2];
    cout<<"MA 1: "<<&arr[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"MA 2: "<<&arr[1]<<endl;
    cout<<"MA 3: "<<&arr[2]<<endl;
```

Output

```
MA 1: 0x7ffd33eba040
MA 2: 0x7ffd33eba044
MA 3: 0x7ffd33eba048
```

Here is the full code. Either arr[2] or arr[3] would be commented out.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[2];
        cout<<"MA 1: "<<&arr[0]<<endl;
        cout<<"MA 2: "<<&arr[1]<<endl;
        cout<<"MA 3: "<<&arr[2]<<endl;
        
    // int arr[3];
    //     cout<<"MA 1: "<<&arr[0]<<endl;
    //     cout<<"MA 2: "<<&arr[1]<<endl;
    //     cout<<"MA 3: "<<&arr[2]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It means absolutely nothing. Low-level details that are specific to your hardware and compiler. On some platforms the address even changes every time you run your program, no matter how big your array is!

Comment: I understand that it's low level details, i'm just curious why always for array[3]

Comment: Purely by random chance. All the factors that play in the role of producing the executable and its memory layout, most of which are particular to your specific operating system and compiler. If you understand that "it's low level details", then you should understand that nobody will be able to tell you the exact reason without knowing what all those low-level factors are.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: It is not random chance, and, yes, stating the exact reason may require knowing what some (not all) low-level factors are, and that is what OP is asking.

Comment: @KernelBash: So ABIs (rules for how routines communicate through function calls and how they manage the stack and processor registers) require 16-byte alignment at certain points. If the platform you are using requires 16-byte alignment for a certain part of the stack frame, the address will end in 0 there. Then the compiler may need to put some additional data, such as a return address or frame pointer. If it needs to put in 12 bytes of additional data (or 28 or 44), then the address at the “bottom” of that data will end in 4. Then if an array of 12 bytes is next, its address will end in C.

Comment: @KernelBash: So that is one way this can happen. Note that if you define other things in your routine besides the array, the compiler might put them first (higher in the stack) instead of the array. It does not necessarily arrange things on the stack in the order you declare them in source code. So the addresses could vary. Or this could be coincidence, that it just happens in the particular trials you tested, you got addresses ending in C, but any minor variation will change that. Turning optimization on or off might change that.

Comment: @KernelBash: For definitive answers, you would need to state the platform you are executing on, the compiler you are using, the version of the compiler, the options you used to compile, and complete source code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik appreciate your responses, just was curious if there may have been a pattern that was more obvious.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks, im using macbook but using online gpp compiler. Actually the complete source code was what I attached, as I was just experimenting with this particular thing.

Comment: @KernelBash: Complete source code includes a `main` routine; it means a complete file (or files) that can be compiled and executed without needing any additions or changes.

Comment: Those addresses are not physical addresses. They're logical (fake) addresses generated by your operating system. Physical location at which your program is loaded every time you run it might be different but the operating system gives it the same logical address space every time you run it.

Comment: @digito_evo: Good modern multiuser systems use address space layout randomization to thwart some attacks, so virtual addresses vary from run to run.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Yes but not always. If the executable is not relocatable then that's not possible. Of course this doesn't affect the randomization of the physical addresses.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Right, I updated the main Q to include the full source code, thanks.

Comment: Address Space Layout Randomization is irrelevant. Exact details vary, but no system touches the lower 12 bits. This question is only about the lowest 4 bits.

Comment: @MSalters clearly there is still a pattern, therefore a reason. I have run the code on 3 different compliers and when the array[3], the final bit is always c. When the size of the array is anything else (array[!3]), the final bit is always zero.

Answer (score 4):

> What does this 'c' at the end of the first address space stand for?

Memory addresses are numbers. When you output a pointer, it is represented by the number of the pointed memory address.

In 0x7ffe3269ca7c the 0x prefix implies that the following number is in [radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) 16 and 7ffe3269ca7c are the digits of that number. The right most digit is the least significant one.

c is a hexadecimal digit whose decimal value is 12.

Comment: Got it, so 'c' stands for 12.

Comment: @KernelBash: What's signigicant here is that 12 is a multiple of 4, which is your `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Ok so the size of my array is 4 and last element of the address space is 12 (c). But if my array size is 3 (array[2]), then 12 is also a multiple of 3.